# Чудовищная чушь

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов, словосочетания

В одной из политических (в форме диспута) передач прозвучало такое предложение:
**Вы мелете чудовищную чушь!**

Удивилась-поразилась: словосочетание показалось мне каким-то странным что ли — "состыковались" почти книжное слово и разговорное.

Пример употребления обнаружился у Б. Акунина в [Левиафане](http://book-online.com.ua/read.php?book=3362&page=81):
*Русский подошел ко мне, поблагодарил за спасение корабля и с фальшивым участием, заикаясь на каждом слове, стал нести невообразимую, **чудовищную чушь***.

И все равно, мне это выражение кажется в чём-то неверным. Или всё правильно?
Какая же она — чудовищная чушь?

Answer (score 1):

Не только неблагозвучно (чу-чу), но и нелепо, по-моему.  Очень сильное слово "чудовищный" рядом со словом, которое обозначает вздор и чепуху, то есть вещи "легкие" и пустые, которым не принято придавать трагический или  вселенский масштаб (огромный, чудовищный).

Answer (score 0):

У слова чудовищный есть ещё и переносные  значения "крайний в своём проявлении" и разговорное "крайне большой, весьма значительный"(Ожегов).

По-моему,чудовищная чушь как крайней степени нелепость вполне нормально смотрится в современном языке. Мы во многих случаях не связываем старославянизмы с высоким стилем. Почему чудовищный аппетит можно сказать, а чудовищная чушь - нет?

Comment: И торжественное слово хождение - тоже старославянизм, но мы употребляем его в переносном разговорном значении: Прекратите хождения, сядьте на место!

Comment: Счастливы ученики (или просто дети), которые слышат  такое , а не что-то вроде "не маячь"!

Comment: У чудовища есть аппетит,  как и у зверя, поэтому он вполне может быть и чудовищный,  и звериный.  "Чудовищем"  зачастую в литературе называют злодея, который совершает " чудовещные" поступки. Чушь этот чудовищный злодей, как правило, не несёт,  потому, " чудовищный аппетит" нам привычнее " чудовищной чуши". " На эмоциях" можно дать для чуши и покрепче определение,  а человек уровновешенный вполне обойдётся словосочетанием - " полная чушь".  Это достаточно ёмкое выражение.

Comment: Мне кажется, проблема в том, что "чушь" - уже "крайняя степень" нелепости, т.е., употребляя *чудовищный*, мы делаем шаг к плеоназму. (PS готический чудовищный стиль - вот еще одно интересное значение)

Comment: Нет, в словаре чушь - просто ерунда, нелепость. Ч. несет (порет) кто-н. (говорит полную чушь). Так что усилительные слова там употребляются. Синонимов у слова много, все означают ту или иную степень нелепости. Есть "чушь какая-то", есть полная чушь, а есть чудовищная - это уже крайняя степень.,

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, это **звукопись**.

Чудо — от чувство, чушь (у Шанского)— от чужь, чуждый.  Получается нечто "чувствам чуждое". Очень благозвучно.

Из Нацкорпуса: Господи, о чем я? **Чушь, чушь, какая чудовищная чушь,** Господи! Ступайте, господин Путилин. [Леонид Юзефович. Дом свиданий (2001)]